# Django почему ошибки в форме выводятся на английском?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть модель, и я вывожу её на страницу через класс наследованный от `CreateView`:

```
class UserView(CreateView):
  model = User
  template_name = 'user/user_form.html'
  fields = ['name', 'adress']

  def form_valid(self, form):
    return super(UserView, self).form_valid(form)
```

В `settings.py` указан Русский `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'`

Но когда я отображаю форму на странице, через: `{{ form.as_p }}`

Все ошибки отображаются на английском, как включить русский?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На английском выводит потому что это язык программирования, а если нужно на русском, то есть библиотека "translate" она переводит текст на русский, больше вариантов нет.